# java.lang.RuntimeException: Port 8686 is not available for the internal rmi registry

Tags: java

While deploying an ear on glassfish i am getting this error.
Does anyone know how to fix this issue

```
[#|2015-08-04T05:10:40.077+0000|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.RuntimeException: Port 8686 is not available for the internal rmi registry. This means that a call was made with the same port, without closing earlier registry instance. This has to do with the system jmx connector configuration in admin-service element of the configuration associated with this instance
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.RMIConnectorStarter._startRegistry(RMIConnectorStarter.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.RMIConnectorStarter.startRegistry(RMIConnectorStarter.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.RMIConnectorStarter.<init>(RMIConnectorStarter.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.startConnector(JMXStartupService.java:278)
    at org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.run(JMXStartupService.java:322)
|#]
```

I made sure that none of the process is using port 8686 using netstat command still i am getting the same issue.

Comment: Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug in Glassfish, q.v. [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-12648).  Could you try upgrading to Glassfish `4.x`?  The bug is reported as being fixed, but I'm not sure which version `3.x` has the fix in it.  You should be fine with Glassfish `4.x` so long as you have JDK 7 and above.

With regards to the cause of this bug, here is an excerpt from the link I cited above:

> I did some investigation and found that our startup code calls
>   LocateRegistry.createRegistry(), but shutdown code never unexports the registry,
>   so subsequent createRegistry fails. Look at the discussion [1](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-12648) to understand
>   what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

try this

1) `netstat -a -o -n` and it will bring up a network list,search for the local address like `127.0.0.1:8686` and note the PID (eq 3624).

2) `taskkill /F /PID 3624` . Run this command to kill that process.